# Python prevent os.getcwd() to give lower case results on windows using MKS shell

Tags: python, mks

On Windows if i use MKS toolkit shell, `os.getcwd()` function returns value in lower case. However on using windows cmd, it returned exact path.

Is it possible in Python by any means for `os.getcwd()` to return the exact path (without converting to lower case on Windows)?

Comment: On my windows machine it doesn't return lowercase strings: `import os;
print os.getcwd()`: `C:\\Users\\aaa`

Comment: Which Python version are you using?  On 2.x, you should also try `os.getcwdu()` to get the path as `unicode` object.

Comment: Its 2.7. Looks like problem is due to mks toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure about this behavior? It's not documented, seems counter-intuitive, and I'm not able to reproduce it (on Windows 7 using Python 2.7.2):

```
>>> import os
>>> print os.getcwd()
C:\Users\foofoofoo
```

Note the capital characters at the start.

Comment: Actually i am using mks toolkit shell, on cmd window. it worked fine. Thanks, i'll edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Before starting Python and using os.getcwd(), in your console you probably used "cd c:\your_path". It matters if this 'c' is lower or upper.